# Spiderfy all Leaflet markerClusters with fewer than 5 markers

Tags: leaflet, markers

I am making a Leaflet map using [markerCluster.js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).
I would like to make all clusters with fewer than 5 markers automatically "spider", regardless of the zoom level. For example in the image below, I'd like the two clusters of 2 to be "spiderfied" regardless of the zoom, without having to get to the maxZoomLevel of my map.

[image]

I assume I need to do something along the lines of the pseudocode:

```
if (markerGroup.getChildCount() < 5) {
     markerGroup.Spiderfy()
}
```

However, I'm not sure exactly where to do this.

I tried adding a this after the map constructor. The first cluster is drawn open (spiderfied), but the rest are still closed. Also after I zoom, the one that was open closes.

```
  map.eachLayer(function(layer){     //iterate over map rather than clusters
     if (layer.getChildCount){         // if layer is markerCluster
           if (layer._childCount < 5){
              layer.spiderfy();
              console.log(layer._childCount);  // log count of points within each cluster
           }
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/502#issuecomment-101837961) "You can only have one cluster spiderfied at a time though". It is from 2015 but I assume it is still valid.

An alternative could perhaps be to try to customize the cluster icon instead to be like a spider web (for `n` < some limit). I tested modifying [the Leaflet.markercluster example](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html), to have the clusters show a list of the numbers associated with all its markers instead of the original sum of all the numbers, and I got it [working](https://jsfiddle.net/djr4e0k9/3/):

[image: map screenshot]
Of course that does not look good, but it should be a starting point.

The key part of it is the following

```
iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
  var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
  var n = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    n.push(markers[i].number);
  }
  var divContent = n.join(', ');
  var size = calculateSize(divContent, { });
  var divWrapper = '<div style="background-color: red; width: ' + size.width
    + '; height: ' + size.height + '">' +  divContent + '</div>';
  return L.divIcon({ html: divWrapper, className: 'mycluster' });
},
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up changing directions completely and making little stacked chips using Carto's method instead. Which looks similar to what you posted.  http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/1e45bdd58994aee8293d